# Can a pokemon go plus pair with multiple phones?

Tags: pokemon-go, android

I have only been able to successfully pair my pokemon go plus with one particular phone (a Note Edge). I've tried pairing the same pokemon go plus with other phones (not simultaneously but at different times) including a galaxy s6, and a number of other android phones and it fails to pair. So, this has me wondering whether a single pokemon go plus will pair with other phones.

I am also curious about known pairing issues of the pokemon go plus.

Answer (score 6):

As stated on [Pokémon Go Plus Support](https://niantic.helpshift.com/a/pokemon-go/?p=web&s=accessories&f=troubleshooting-the-pokemon-go-plus), in order to use Pokémon Go Plus an another device, you need to unpair with the device it is currently linked to.

> **Troubleshooting**
>
> *Unpairing Pokémon GO Plus from your device*
>
> To use the Pokémon GO Plus with another device, you’ll need to unpair the Pokémon GO Plus.
>
> 1. Press the function button. The light will flash blue, indicating that the accessory is paired.
> 2. Wait until the accessory has stopped blinking.
> 3. Press and hold the function button for 5 seconds. The indicator light will turn solid blue.
> 4. Release the function button.
> 5. While the light is solid blue, press and hold the function button for another 5 seconds. When the Pokémon GO Plus vibrates, it has been successfully unpaired from your device.
>
> [image]

Comment: It is not sufficient to be unconnected? You have to actually perform an unpair?

Comment: @user55570 This does appear to be the case. I'm sure it is a software configuration that permanently pairs it until the user unpairs it